# Authorized, but not authorized in OAuth

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to make OAuth work for me for the first time. Using [this](http://www.oauthforaspnet.com/providers/google/) as a basis I've created an out-of-the-box MVC app with the Authentication set to "Individual User Accounts". I've modified my Startup.Auth.cs file to look like this...

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        var googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "blah",
            ClientSecret = "blah-blah",
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLoginCallback"),
            Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = async ctx =>
                {
                    string accessToken = ctx.AccessToken;
                    string googleName = ctx.Name;
                    string googleEmailAddress = ctx.Email;
                    var serializedUser = ctx.User;
                }
            }
        };
        googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file");
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
    }
}
```

Obviously, in my real code I have real values for ClientId and ClientSecret.

When I run the app, the start page shows.

When I click on "Log In" I see an option to log in via Google.

Clicking that shows me the Consent screen.

But this is what I don't understand. When I click on **Allow** my app redirects to `http://localhost/WebApplication2/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied#`

I'm clearly doing something wrong, I just can't figure out what. Can anyone offer any clues?